# Execute Terminal Command fails in BetterTouchTool. Why?

Tags: macos, terminal, bettertouchtool

I've installed [Ouimeaux](http://ouimeaux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to control a Belkin Wemo on OSX, and it's working correctly in Terminal - meaning that the following command in Terminal will toggle my Wemo switch on/off:

```
wemo switch Myswitchname toggle
```

It works.  Now, I'd like to assign a hotkey to that with BetterTouchTool.  It seems like it'd be as easy as selecting the option to Execute Terminal Command in BetterTouchTool...  but pressing the hotkey does nothing.  It works in Terminal though.  Do I need to write it differently for BetterTouchTool?

Answer (score 3):

I feel silly for not figuring this out myself, but I'll post it here in case anyone else is having a similar issue.

In Terminal, I can simply type this command and it works:

```
wemo switch Myswitchname toggle
```

But with the Execute Terminal Command in BetterTouchTool, it needed to be entered this way in order to work:

```
/usr/local/bin/wemo switch Myswitchname toggle
```

Comment: I couldn't figure it out either, thanks for sharing.

Comment: I bet this has to do with your `.bash_profile` not being sourced by non-login sessions.  If your `PATH` is set there, you won't be able to depend on that PATH from BTT.  If you set your PATH in `.bashrc` instead it will probably work.  (I haven't tested it but just mentioning it here in case it helps someone.)

Comment: BTT currently explicitly states that "Be sure to use absolute paths to any executable, as BTT doesn't source your PATH or other settings."