# Execute terminal command "rsync" from BetterTouchTool

Tags: terminal, bash, bettertouchtool

I have created a Bash command that will copy the contents of one folder into another, and it works as expected from inside Terminal.

```
rsync -r /Users/owendostie/Dropbox/Ohouse /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Ohouse
```

However, when I attempt to create a hotkey to execute this command using BetterTouchTool, nothing happens. I found [another user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157631/execute-terminal-command-fails-in-bettertouchtool-why) who has encountered a similar problem, but I do not know enough about Terminal for his answer to be helpful. What do I need to change about my command to get it to run from inside BetterTouchTool?

Answer (score 1):

According to the format of the answer to that question, you'd want to specify the full path to the rsync program. I looked around a bit and found my rsync executable inside the folder /usr/bin/.
If your rsync is in the same place (it should be), you should modify your command in BetterTouchTool to:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -r /Users/owendostie/Dropbox/Ohouse /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Ohouse
```

Unfortunately I don't use BTT so I can't test this, but that is how the other answer solved the issue.

Comment: Your suggestion makes perfect sense, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe it has something to do with user permissions?